# inner join pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, inner-join

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
pd.merge(lessons, attendances, on=['_id', 'lessonId'], how='inner')
attendances
```

пытаюсь соединить таблицы, где колонки с разными именами. не знаю, как это сделать

вот такой прогресс:

```
bd = pd.merge(lessons, attendances, on=[lessons['_id'], attendances['lessonId']], how='left')
bd
```

ошибка:

```
Execution Error

KeyError: 0        61a0e8b84a6fa5a2926ceef7
1        61a102444a6fa5a2926cef27
2        61a1085f4a6fa5a2926cef5e
3        61a1143a4a6fa5a2926cefc4
4        61a114fd4a6fa5a2926cefe7
                   ...           
18586    651a4ba5df486ca8a61fd400
18587    651a55d9df486ca8a61fd780
18588    651a55f7df486ca8a61fd7ad
18589    651a560ddf486ca8a61fd7d9
18590    651a7474df486ca8a61fdf57
Name: _id, Length: 18591, dtype: object
```

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Comment: у меня вопрос по синтаксису, данные не важны

Comment: Ну вы нашли в документации описание параметров left_on и right_on для метода merge?

Comment: да, сейчас обновлю вопрос

Comment: я вас спросил об одном, а вы написали о другом. еще раз: `left_on` и `right_on`

Comment: Ну да, там же специально сделаны отдельные параметры, где можно указать, какие поля брать у таблицы слева и какие у таблицы справа.

Answer (score 0):

```
bd = pd.merge(lessons, attendances, left_on=lessons['_id'], right_on=attendances['lessonId'], how='inner')
```